# How do I display the current users details after sign in?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a user who lands on the `/sign-in` page which triggers the `signIn` action in the `sessions` controller.

This is what I suspect happens, when the user first lands on the `/sign-in` page:

1. The `model` and `afterModel` hooks would have already executed. And since `this.currentSession.get('isAuthenticated')` is false, it never sets the `model`.
2. When the user successfully signs in, and is transitioned to the `articles.index`, the `model` and `afterModel` hooks are not called again.
3. The application template renders `undefined` for `{{log model.profile.imageUrl}}` and no profile image is displayed

Application route:

```
model() {
  if (this.currentSession.get('isAuthenticated')) {
    console.log('in application route');
    return this.store.findRecord('user', this.currentSession.get('id'));
  }
},

afterModel: function(model, transition) {
  // if (this.currentSession.get('isAuthenticated')) {
  if (Ember.isPresent(model)) {
    return model.get('profile');
  }
}
```

Application template:

```
{{log model.profile.imageUrl}}
{{image-tag imageUrl=model.profile.imageUrl size="mini" class="-small -round"}}
```

Sessions controller (`/sign-in`):

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    signIn(content) {
      // For the sake of simplicity, this is supposed to execute a Ember.$.ajax
      this.currentSession.set('token', 'abc123');
      this.transitionToRoute('articles.index');
    }
  }
});
```

The Current Session service has:

```
isAuthenticated: Ember.computed('token', {
  get() {
    return Ember.isPresent(this.get('token'));
  }
}),
```

I can fix this by forcing a page reload after successfull sign in. In the `signIn` action, I can replace

```
this.transitionToRoute('articles.index');
```

with

```
document.location = '/articles';
```

which will trigger the `model` and `afterModel` hooks since `this.currentSession.get('isAuthenticated')` is now `true`.

However is `document.location` still appropriate to use today? I normally see this suggestion in Ember tutorials from a few years back.

If not, is there a different approach I can take?

Comment: assuming currentSession is something you control, could you just make currentSession.currentUser a computed property that monitors isAuthenticated and/or token?

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys I madenad edit. `isAuthenticated` is now a computed property that observes `token`. If a `token` is set, then `currentSession.get('isAuthenticated')` is `true`. Problem is the same as I described. i.e the `model` and `afterModel` hooks are not triggered after sign in

Comment: I think the issue is not in the way the CP is defined. But on the fact that the `model` and `afterModel` hooks in the application route have already executed

Comment: ah yeah, i meant get rid of the model and afterModel hooks completely, and just use currentSession.currentUser in your template (you need to define currentSession.currentUser)

Answer (score 0):

[Route.transitionTo(route)](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo) or [Controller.transitionToRoute(route)](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute) without a model object passed, *should* trigger the model hook to run.  You can also pass a simple value like 1 or "stuff" instead of an object and that will map into the [dynamic segments](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments) in your URL if you have any.

It seems like the value you're trying to check is not coming from the model on the route you're currently on, rather the Application Route's Model.  The Application Route's model is not being called again when you move to any sub-route within the Application.  This is why window.location works, because you're reloading the entire Ember App by hitting the URL again from the top level in the browser.  I would recommend re-designing your data structure so that the token and isAuthenticated flags can be updated within the current Route and fetched via its model() rather than via the Application Route only

Also since you already have the UserSession service, you could just inject that into all your routes and add the user details to the Routes that need it via afterModel() on those routes.  For example:

```
// some route that cares about user
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
      afterModel: afterModel(model) {
          model.session = this.currentSession; // the session service injected
          // or whatever data points
          model.userName = this.currentSession.userName;
          // model.whatever here is already set by the model hook or passed by transitionTo() etc.
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is what I was suggesting.

Application route:

```
// this space intentionally left blank
```

Application template:

```
{{#if currentSession.isAuthenticated}}
  {{log currentSession.currentUser.profile.imageUrl}}
  {{image-tag imageUrl=currentSession.currentUser.profile.imageUrl size="mini" class="-small -round"}}
{{/if}}
```

Sessions controller (/sign-in):

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    signIn(content) {
      // For the sake of simplicity, this is supposed to execute a Ember.$.ajax
      this.currentSession.set('token', 'abc123');
      this.transitionToRoute('articles.index');
    }
  }
});
```

The Current Session service:

```
isAuthenticated: Ember.computed('token', {
  get() {
    return Ember.isPresent(this.get('token'));
  }
}),
currentUser: Ember.computed('isAuthenticated', {
  // some ajax call to get your current user
})
```

Comment: `currentUser` in the current session service will always return a promise. Unfortunately, simply doing `currentSession.currentUser.profile.imageUrl` in the template will not render the `imageUrl`